# Database connection with Heroku && Play 2.4 && Slick 3.1

Tags: postgresql, heroku, playframework-2.0, slick

I have problem with connection to database PostgreSQL on Heroku.

There are throw an error:
Unexpected exception[SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 1000ms of waiting for a connection.]

My "Procfile":

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/blog -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
```

My Database config from application.conf:

```
slick.dbs.default {
  driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
  db.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
  db.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/blog"
  db.user="rumata"
  db.password="rumata"
}
```